# Problemas en una consulta con tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql

No soy experto en SQL y tengo el siguiente problema... dispongo de dos tablas "relacionadas", una de productos y otra de caracteristicas de productos en las que guardo valores que pueden tener esos productos, por ejemplo: colores, materiales, tamaños, etc...

Lo que estoy haciendo es un filtro que me saque productos según las caracteristicas seleccionadas pero tengo el problema a la hora de sacar los resultados con la siguiente sentencia:

```
SELECT 
    productos.ref,productos.nombre,caracteristicas.ref,caracteristicas.idvalor 
FROM productos 
LEFT JOIN 
    caracteristicas ON (caracteristicas.ref=productos.ref)  
WHERE 
    (caracteristicas.idvalor = 384 OR caracteristicas.idvalor = 379 ) and 
    (caracteristicas.idvalor = 377) 
ORDER BY 
    productos.nombre ASC
```

Antes lo tenia todo con un `IN` al estilo...  `caracteristicas.idvalor IN (384,379,377)` lo que no quiero que saque los productos que tengan esas caracteristicas, sino que la consulta sea...

Productos que tengan 384 ó 379 y además tengan 377.

no se si me explico?

La consulta no da error, pero no me devuelve resultados habiendo registros que cumplen esas condiciones.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pero no puede ser que el mismo campo, en este caso `caracteristicas.idvalor` tenga dos valores diferentes como dices. 384 o 379 y además 377

Comment: @rencinas sí podría ser, si `idvalor` representa elementos como `tamaño, color, materiales`, o sea, creo que él busca productos que tengan *tamaño grande `384` o color rojo `379` y que sean de algodón `377`*...   (aunque quizá el diseño de las tablas no sea el más adecuado), que es, creo yo, el problema de fondo aquí... quizá deberías replantear el diseño de tus tablas aLifer... aunque no podría decirte más porque tampoco tu pregunta no es del todo clara, ni en cuanto al diseño de las tablas ni en cuanto al resultado que esperas obtener.

Comment: habría que ver una muestra de los datos para saber si lo estas planteando bien al `(A=1 or A=2) AND A=3` pues así como está dará false siempre el `where`

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que me refiero, imaginemos que es cantidad/color/el valor que prefieras. Es que si la columna `idvalor` tiene el valor 384 para la fila 2, ese mismo campo, dentro de esa misma fila, no podría cumplir la característica de que fuera también 377. Eso, o no he entendido bien la pregunta/ejemplo.

Comment: así como está planteado la condición da falso, me da la sensación de que habría que agrupar o hacer una subconsulta

Comment: @rencinas yo lo que entiendo es que en la tabla `caracteristicas_productos` él tiene una mezcla de todo, de `colores, materiales, tamaño`. Y que en esa tabla por ejemplo el id `384` representa el tamaño `XL`, el id `379` representa el color `rojo`,  y el id `377` representa el material `algodón`. Entonces en la consulta él busca un producto que sea: `de tamaño XL OR de color rojo AND de material algodón`. Eso es lo que yo entiendo, viendo su consulta.

Comment: pues hay que replantear el where porque así como está da `(true) and false = false` ó `(false) and true = false` ó `(false) and false = false`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la consulta con varias subconsultas, realizando un NATURAL JOIN entre estas. Por ejemplo los Productos que tengan 384 ó 379 en la consulta A, y por otra parte los productos que tengan 377 en la consulta B. Una vez tengas estás características y realizando el NATURAL JOIN te quedarás con los elementos de ambas consultas que cumplan la condición (que entiendo que quieres).

Cómo te han dicho el 'caracteristicas.idvalor' no puede tener dos valores a la vez por lo que tendrás que hacer uso de alías para designar dos o más tablas caracteristicas.

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de tu misma consulta, con un **exists** puedes hacerlo.

```
SELECT 
    productos.ref,productos.nombre,caracteristicas.ref,caracteristicas.idvalor 
FROM productos 
LEFT JOIN 
    caracteristicas ON (caracteristicas.ref=productos.ref)  
WHERE 
    (caracteristicas.idvalor = 384 OR caracteristicas.idvalor = 379 ) 
and   exists (select 1 from caracteristicas as cx where cx.idvalor = 377 and cx.ref =  caracteristicas.Ref) 
ORDER BY 
    productos.nombre ASC
```